# SQL - Convert String Values to a Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

*Find the same day of same week of the previous month for 2014/12/01. Result should be 2014/11/03.*

My approach is taking the values of the original input date 2014/12/01 and breaking them down to their component parts (Month-(1), Day Name, Day Value, Week of Month, Year) with the below query:

I've put together a SQLFiddle query to determine all of the output values:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2014-12-01'

SELECT 
  (month(@date)-1) as 'Month',
  datename(dw, @date) as 'Day Name',
  datepart(dw, @date) as 'Day Value',
  (DATEPART(WEEK, @DATE) - DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,@DATE), 0))+ 1) as 'Week of Month',
  year(@date) as 'Year';
```

The output for this query below:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Month | Day Name | Day Value |  Week of Month | Year |
-----------------------------------------------------
11    | Monday   | 2         |  1             | 2014 |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

What I'd NEXT like to do is take the component parts and turn them back into a date time value so I can get a a solution output of '2014/11/03'.

I'm struggling with this part of the request as I can't find a built-in function to turn a **day name** and **day of week** for a **given month** to an actual datetime output.

Help please! Thanks in advance greatly for your feedback.

Comment: (1) your best bet is going to be a calendar table. (2) you will need to decide what you want to do when there is no answer; say, when the input date is the 5th Tuesday in March.

Comment: Also, please use `[square brackets]` or `"double quotes"` for alias delimiters (when necessary); `'single quotes'` make them look like string literals (plus some forms as aliases using single quotes are deprecated).

Comment: Can't you just do -28 days, or if day of month > 28, do -35 days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Query

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2014-12-01'

;WITH DATES AS 
 (
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -40 ,@DATE) AS DateData
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY , 1 ,DateData) 
  FROM DATES 
  WHERE DateData < @DATE
)
SELECT * 
FROM DATES
WHERE MONTH(DateData) = MONTH(@DATE) - 1
 AND  FLOOR((DAY(DateData)-1)/7)+1 = FLOOR((DAY(@DATE)-1)/7)+1
 AND  DATEPART(WEEKDAY,DateData) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@Date)
```

### Result:

```
2014-11-03 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: I have made a minor change instead of going back 1 month from the start date, go back 40 days just in case the week and day of start date falls into more than a month (30) ago in last month.

Comment: Hey there, thank you very much for providing feedback to this personally challenging inquiry. I'm still wrapping my head around your solution.

Comment: Not a problem mate, all I have done is created a recursive query to generate date range from last 40 days, and then simply added some where clauses to get the date where `the same day of same week of the previous month` criteria is true.